# Solspace Calendar out of range dates

Tags: solspace-calendar

I am using Solspace Calendar. I would like to know how to hide the out of range dates (last month and next month day cells) and only display the current month dates.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"` (to cover all days of the current month, for example), add **`pad_short_weeks="n"`** to avoid Calendar from including extra days part of a full week row. More details on this can be found here:

http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/calendar/#pad_short_weeks

Of course, this is for the `{exp:calendar:cal}` tag **only**.